# Switch off "on page" for varioref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, varioref

For referencing I'm using the three packages

```
\usepackage{varioref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
```

In the text I cite with `\vref`, which is redefined by `cleveref` and does its job very well. Now I have to publish a paper where "on page .." from the `varioref` needs to much space. Is there an option to switch it off? Or do I have to change everything to `\cref`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the `varioref` manual for macros starting with `\reftext`. You could re-define them to be empty (with `\renewcommand*` or `\def`).

```
\def\reftextfaceafter{}%
\def\reftextfacebefore{}%
\def\reftextafter{}%
\def\reftextbefore{}%
\def\reftextcurrent{}%
\def\reftextfaraway#1{}%
\def\reftextpagerange#1#2{}%
\def\reftextlabelrange#1#2{}%
```

You could also try to define the macros of `varioref` to be those of `cleveref`, e.g.

```
\let\vref\cref
\let\Vref\Cref
\let\vrefrange\crefrange
% etc.
```

but changing the `\reftext…` macros is definitely easier.

Comment: I know this possibility. However, it is not very nice and I hoped to missed an option.
The second option can cause issue, I think, because the `\vref` is redefined through `cleveref`.
I think until now, I will do a search and replace.

Comment: @Dirk Eight redefinitions and you’re done. Nice enough for me. ;) `\let\vref\cref` just copies the definition of `\cref` to `\vref` (overwriting a previous definition if one existed), so you could even _not load_ `varioref`.

Comment: With no option available, you are right. I will try it. Thank you!